# Slice pandas dataframe using .loc with both index values and multiple column values, then set values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe, and I would like to select a subset of the dataframe using both index and column values. I can do both of these separately, but cannot figure out the syntax to do them simultaneously. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe:
cid=[1,2,3,4,5,6,17,18,91,104]
c1=[1,2,3,1,2,3,3,4,1,3]
c2=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c1,c2)),columns=['col1','col2'],index=cid)
df
```

Returns:

```
    col1    col2
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   1   0
5   2   1
6   3   1
17  3   1
18  4   1
91  1   0
104 3   1
```

Using .loc, I can collect by index:

```
rel_index=[5,6,17]
relc1=[2,3]
relc2=[1]
df.loc[rel_index]
```

Returns:

```
    col1    col2
5   1   5
6   2   6
17  3   7
```

Or I can select by column values:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(relc1) & df['col2'].isin(relc2)]
```

Returning:

```
    col1    col2
5   2   1
6   3   1
17  3   1
104 3   1
```

However, I cannot do both. When I try the following:

```
df.loc[rel_index,df['col1'].isin(relc1) & df['col2'].isin(relc2)]
```

Returns:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

I have tried a few other variations (such as "&" instead of the ","), but these return the same or other errors.

Once I collect this slice, I am hoping to reassign values on the main dataframe. I imagine this will be trivial once the above is done, but I note it here in case it is not. My goal is to assign something like df2 in the following:

```
c3=[1,2,3]
c4=[5,6,7]
df2=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c3,c4)),columns=['col1','col2'],index=rel_index)
```

to the slice referenced by index and multiple column conditions (overwriting what was in the original dataframe).

Comment: what is your expected output? should it be an intersection or a union of the two sample dataframes?

Comment: Your df2 code fails

Comment: @aydow intersection of the index and column conditions (& not or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the IndexingError, is that you're calling `df.loc` with arrays of 2 different sizes.

`df.loc[rel_index]` has a length of 3 whereas `df['col1'].isin(relc1)` has a length of 10.

You need the index results to also have a length of 10.  If you look at the output of `df['col1'].isin(relc1)`, it is an array of booleans.

You can achieve a similar array with the proper length by replacing `df.loc[rel_index]` with `df.index.isin([5,6,17])`

so you end up with:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin([5,6,17]) & df['col1'].isin(relc1) & df['col2'].isin(relc2)]
```

which returns:

```
    col1  col2
5      2     1
6      3     1
17     3     1
```

That said, I'm not sure why your index would ever look like this.   Typically when slicing by index you would use `df.iloc` and your index would match the 0,1,2...etc. format.

Alternatively, you could first search by value - then assign the resulting dataframe to a new variable `df2`

`df2 = df.loc[df['col1'].isin(relc1) & df['col2'].isin(relc2)]`

then `df2.loc[rel_index]` would work without issue.

As for your overall goal, you can simply do the following:

```
c3=[1,2,3]
c4=[5,6,7]
df2=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c3,c4)),columns=['col1','col2'],index=rel_index)

df.loc[df.index.isin([5,6,17]) & df['col1'].isin(relc1) & df['col2'].isin(relc2)] = df2
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rexovas explains it quite well, this is an alternative, where you can compute the filters on the index before assigning - it is a bit long, involves MultiIndex, but once you get your head around MultiIndex, should be intuitive:

```py
(df
# move columns into the index
.set_index(['col1', 'col2'], append = True)
# filter based on the index
.loc(axis = 0)[rel_index, relc1, relc2]
# return cols 1 and 2
.reset_index(level = [-2, -1])
# assign values
.assign(col1 = c3, col2 = c4)
)

    col1  col2
5      1     5
6      2     6
17     3     7
```